# My Spyder won't find my modules on my computer

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

I´m trying to write this code that I will show in the image below but, apparently, spyder won´t find my ds_charts module, even though I already have it in the same folder as my profile.py document.

Does anyone have a clue about this?

[1st image - Spyder´s code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcMmR.png)

[2nd image - My folders image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDMzP.png)

Answer (score 1):

Your console working directory (path in the upper right of the first image) is not the same as the path to the directory your file is in (upper left). Right-click the tab of your .py file and set the working directory:

[image: spyder set console working directory]